# How can I modify the title of a category in magento?

Tags: category, store-view

I'm looking to add a simple `<hr>` beneath the category name of every single product view page. Where can i locate the file responsible and at what line?

Comment: The product list page, which shows all of the products in a specific category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`.
If there is none in your theme copy it from the `base/default` theme and add `<hr />` after this line

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
```

but if you need a simple line below the category title you should do it via css.

```
.catalog-category-view .category-title h1 {
   border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}
```

`catalog-category-view` is the body class for every category page `.category-title` is the class for the element that wraps the `h1` tag.

You might want to change the color of the border to fit your needs.